# Wiring power new power button to UPS power module for raspberry pi

Tags: button, wires, raspberrypi

I have a UPS Power Module Expansion Board for Raspberry Pi 3B/3B+(Plus) and removed the power button because it is in the way and would like to attach this read button instead. But it is not working, they board does not turn on?

Am i wiring the incorrectly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you want to replace an on/off switch with momentary button? and where is the Arduino?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a momentary push-button; use a latching button (push-on/push-off) instead.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out :)